# How to print a captcha image by function?

Tags: php, captcha

I have created a function called createCaptcha

```
function createCaptcha()
{
    $ranStr = md5(microtime());
    $ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
    $_SESSION['cap_code'] = $ranStr;
    $newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("views/cap_bg.jpg");
    $txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
    imagejpeg($newImage);
}
```

but when i call this function it shows some strange characters!!!!

```
<label for="captchacheck">Word Verification : </label>
Type the characters in the picture below<br /><br/>

<div id="captchadiv">
<img id="captchaimg" src="<?php createCaptcha(); ?>" /></div><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="captchacheck" id="captchacheck" style="width:200px;"/>
<br /><br />
```

**After adding content type inside the function,**

```
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

The whole page becomes an image

but i only want this to work in img tag

Any help will be thankful....

Comment: Your `src` attribute has to point to an _image_, or a URI that renders an image with the appropriate content type (e.g. `/captcha` being the view that sends image/jpeg based on the session). You can't put a binary blob of data in the `src` attribute, which is what others in comments and answers have been trying to tell you. Just make a view and controller that generates an image, and call _that_ in the `src` attribute. This question is _extremely_ localized and (unfortunately) not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it, the src attribute of an img tag points to an image file, not image data. So put the createCaptcha() function in some file like captcha.php and set the src to that.
`<img id="captchaimg" src="captcha.php" />`

Comment: But i use MVC architecture 
Actually we uses a function called addTag to replace a tag with the given value
eg: 
<img id="captchaimg" src="{captcha_img}" />

add in the function we add addTag('captcha_img',$this->ceateCaptcha());

Comment: @Peace Still, the result will be `<img src="{lots of binary gobblegoock}">`, which is nonsense. MVC has nothing to do with this. +1 for this answer.

Comment: @deceze Then, How do i do it???

Comment: @Peace Did you read george's answer?

Comment: How others who uses MVC architecture validate using Captcha

Comment: @deceze Yes i did. That's not a method to follow with MVC

Comment: @Peace you have to change your MVC function. it is not the problem with the answer. it is your problem and you have to solve it, using your "MVC architecture".

Comment: @Mr. Col That's what i'm asking your support how to do it.Understand???

Comment: @Peace you have to understand your MVC architecture for that. It is your architecture, nobody knows a bit about it. You have been told how to show a captcha. How to add a certain tag in your architecturem you have to know yourself